# How to handle population of env variables

Tags: linux, deployment, environment-variables, ansible, env

While my understanding is that using environment variables for configuring applications in different deployment environments is best practice, I don't know of a good method for managing these environments and populating the variables in them.

Here are the approaches I'm considering:

- Populating them in the Upstart script we use to run our app. We use Ansible to provision our servers which currently copies over a static upstart scrip, however this could be templated with environment variables.
- Same approach but with `/etc/environment`
- Using something like `envdir` and once again using ansible to populate the files.

The other issue is where to store the values, I'm thinking redis, but am open to suggestion. Ansible has a "Vault" that I'm yet to look at which may be an option.

The values are things like API keys and database urls.

I'm really just wondering what approaches other people use. I'm open to all suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

I think this question is going to solicit a lot of opinions, and probably a lot of conflicting  opinions, but with that said here's some of my opinions:

- `/etc/environment` is part of the OS and intended for configuration of interactive user shells. Don't use it for applications.
- A templatized upstart config via ansible seems pretty reasonable to me. Just ensure the filesystem permissions are suitably locked-down to root read only if you intend to store sensitive data there.
- You could also use a templatized application-specific config file such as `/etc/myapp/config` which has worked pretty well for many programs for a few decades. The whole environment-variables-are-better-than-config files position is really coming more from a PaaS perspective (heroku I believed popularized this approach by way of their 12-factor app site). So if you're deployment is PaaS or PaaS-style, envirnoment is convenient. But if you are installing your app on your own servers via Ansible, IMHO a straight-up config file is simpler to troubleshoot for the reasons I outline in my blog post [environment variables considered harmful](http://peterlyons.com/problog/2010/02/environment-variables-considered-harmful)